# Is there any possibility to change the Square keys(Application id and location id) if switches the custom buttons?

Tags: square, angular15

In my system there are two different application id's and location Id's. How to build square payment form different keys. If change the button.

**Example:** There are two buttons, on switch the button build the square payment form based on there own keys.

**Issue:** Now if switch the button, old one is picked.https://codepen.io/harleen21/pen/rNqLROZ

Answer (score 0):

With the Web Payments SDK you'll need to [destroy()](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/sdks/web/payments/objects/Card#Card.destroy) the form and re-initialize it with the second set of credentials to have the values take effect.

Comment: I have already implement this, but not working. Please check this https://codepen.io/harleen21/pen/rNqLROZ